# When using updated over up to date?

Tags: word-choice

> This is like blame and log in that it runs offline and is **up to date** only as of the last time you communicated with the Subversion server.

*[The text above was got from Pro Git book.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)*

When should use *[updated](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-portuguese/updated)* over *[up to date](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/up-to-date)*? Or the two adjectives have the same meaning?

Comment: Have you looked them up in reliable dictionaries? They don't have the same meaning.

Comment: I looked for by *Cambridge Dictionary*: [updated](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-portuguese/updated), and [up to date](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/up-to-date).

Comment: Hrm, I don't like that definition of "updated".  "Updated" just means "revised", not necessarily the newest information. Other changes may have taken place since somebody updated it, so it could be updated, but not up to date at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although often used as an adjective, 'updated' is firstly a verb - the past participle of *to update*. The process of updating something can mean bringing it up to date, but it can also simply mean making it newer than it was. As adjectives, the two are not the same.

Something could be updated yet not be 'up to date'. For example, it's 2022, you own a car made in 1999, and you trade it in for a car made in 2012. You've *updated* your car, but it isn't 'up to date'.

Likewise, something can be 'up to date' having *never* gone through the process of updating. For example, a scientific paper could be 'up to date' when it is written. Years later, if it still holds true to current scientific understanding, you could say that the paper is *still* 'up to date'.